# Caching website to be displayed in offline

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I create a simple winForm application that contain webBrowser tool to get a specific website. How to cache this website to be displayed in offline mode?

Comment: are you the owner of the website? Can you edit it's markup?

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use html5 app cache. You will need to add appropriate manifest and browser control should do the job.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/